# Alternative to the word tinged

Tags: word-request

Is there any alternative to the word **tinged** in the context of the following sentence

> **Tinged** with regret, I disagree with his idea.

Comment: "With some regret...", "With a slight regret...", "It's not without regret that I...", ...

Comment: A person can't be tinged with regret. A tinge is a trace of colour, so we speak of a feeling, such as happiness or relief, being tinged with a contrary emotion such as regret.